# Pipe email - read from stdin - get html table cells values in array - connect to drupal - create new node doesnt seem to work

Tags: php, email, drupal, piping

Title of this question explains the workflow i am trying to achieve.
So i have made email piping to script.php in my c-panel. It works, even though it always returns message: "Mail delivery failed: local delivery failed" to the sender email. But that's not an issue her, i guess :)

I have tested piping with a test script:

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?php
$fd = fopen("php://stdin", "r");
$email = "";
while (!feof($fd)) {
$email .= fread($fd, 1024);
}
fclose($fd);
$filename = rand(7, 100000).'email'.time();
$fdw = fopen("/home/user/public_html/project/emails/" . $filename, "w+");
fwrite($fdw, $email);
fclose($fdw);
?>
```

As a result i get .txt file which contains all the email content.

Lets go further: Now i use this script to capture previously created file, parse it (get all the html table cell values, which is in email body region) and then connect to drupal and finally create node containing html table cell value information:

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?php
$email = file_get_contents("emails/80358email1406727227.txt");
$parsed = getTextBetweenTags('td', $email);
$trimmed_array=array_map('trim',$parsed);

function getTextBetweenTags($tag, $html, $strict=0)
{
//a new dom object 
$dom = new domDocument;

//load the html into the object 
if($strict==1)
{
    $dom->loadXML($html);
}
else
{
    $dom->loadHTML($html);
}

// discard white space 
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

// the tag by its tag name 
$content = $dom->getElementsByTagname($tag);

// the array to return 
$out = array();
foreach ($content as $item)
{
    // add node value to the out array
    $out[] = $item->nodeValue
}
// return the results 
return $out;
}

//connect to drupal
define( 'DRUPAL_ROOT', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] );
$base_url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap( DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL );

//create new node

$node = new stdClass(); 
$node->type = "Task"; 
node_object_prepare($node); 
$node->title    = $trimmed_array[0];
$node->language = 'en'; 
$node->status = 1;
$node->uid = 1; // UID of the author of the node; or use $node->name

$node->field_num['und'][0]['value'] =$trimmed_array[1];
$node->field_status['und'][0]['tid'] = 1 ;
...
node_save($node);
```

I manually execute the code above, it works, it takes .txt file, parses it, saves table cell values in array, connects to drupal, and creates a new node of type "task", but the problem starts when i change
line 
    $email = file_get_contents("emails/80358email1406727227.txt");
to line
    $email = file_get_contents("php://stdin");

so when i send email, it gets piped to script, and it doesnt create a new node.

Im stuck here, any thoughts?
Why script can do the job when opening a .txt file, but does nothing when reads from stdin?

Comment: last script example doesnt have closing php tag ?>, but thats not the problem, in real script i have it.

Comment: You don't need and shouldn't write closing PHP tags anyway.